# Trigger a pipeline with providing all inputs by parameter - Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

In logic app designer, I wanted to trigger a pipeline with providing all inputs by parameter.

[image: Azure Log Apps Design]

In http request I provide all parameters.

```
{
"properties": {
    "Data_Factory_Name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "Data_Factory_Pipeline_Name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "Resource_Group": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "Subscription": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"type": "object"
```

}

I am triggering it from Postman with json parameters in the body.
An example input like:

```
    {
"Resource_Group":"resource_1",
"Data_Factory_Name":"adf-playground",
"Data_Factory_Pipeline_Name":"DummyPipeline Trigger",
"Subscription": "Lorem Ipsum Company"
}
```

Normally if I hard-code Subscription Name as "Lorem Ipsum Company" it works.
But when I send it from postman request it fails.

```
{  "error": {
"code": "InvalidSubscriptionId",
"message": "The provided subscription identifier 'Lorem Ipsum Company' is malformed or invalid."  }}
```

Comment: I'd guess that should be the subscription GUID not it's name

Comment: @Liam, yes you are right. It works with "Subscription Id" which is a GUID pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from our end it is working fine when we have given subscription id instead of its name and also adding parse JSON instead of directly retrieving the properties from the body. Here is my logic app for your reference:

[image]

**output:-**
[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works with "Subscription Id" which is not a "Subscription Name"